# Remove query string and make clean url using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have url's like following with query string. I want to remove query string from url and want to make clean url.

```
www.demo.com/following.php?user=hardik
www.demo.com/fans.php?user=john
```

This url's should be like

```
www.demo.com/hardik/following
www.demo.com/john/fans
```

OR should be like

```
www.demo.com/following/hardik
www.demo.com/fans/john
```

Is this possible with htaccess? I tried to find a loot in google but still no luck. Need help.

Update:

I need something like this

```
www.demo.com/user/hardik/following/
www.demo.com/user/john/fans/
```

I tried like this

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^?]*) following.php?user=$2/ [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ $2.php?user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Q1. What is location of this .htaccess file? Q2. Are there more rules in this file? Q3. What happens when you enter: `www.demo.com/following/hardik` in browser?

Comment: file location is on right place on root. There is one rule for removing index.php. And i see page without css loading.

Comment: Page without css is different problem, you need to provide all details. For that  just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: I check in browser view source and see there is already full url in css/js

Comment: This is redirecting to 404.
#RewriteRule ^user/([^*]+)/following following.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]

this code working for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65819/discussion-between-anubhava-and-hardik).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this for a url like www.demo.com/following/hardik

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$ $1.php?user=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is working for me for my last requirement. May be help someone else.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^user/([^*]+)/following/$ following.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/([^*]+)/fans/$ fans.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```